# why does php implode causes new lines when reading files?

Tags: php, file, line, implode

i am using php to access an html file

```
$file = file("index.html");
```

then I am using

```
file_put_contents( "index.html", implode(PHP_EOL, $file) );
```

but what is going on here?!... there are new lines everywhere... the file is much bigger now, useless new line!!

if I do:

```
file_put_contents( "index.html", implode("", $file) );
```

the problem is fixed...

but if I modify the array `$file`, anything I add will be on the same line. I cannot add new values. what is going on here?!

somehow the strings in the file have new lines encoded in them.... and any string I add does not.

example:
a 10 line file will have a bunch of text. If I read the file and get an array of 10 values, then add 11... using implode("", $file) ); will give... 10 lines!

what happened to my 11th value? it will be on the same line!

how is this possible?! what is going on here?!

Comment: `file()` includes the newlines at the end of each line. Then you're adding another one when you use `implode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `file()` keeps the newlines in the strings that it returns in the array. You get double-spacing if you add another newline between each line with `implode()`. And if you add additional elements to the array, but don't end them with a newline, you'll get inconsistent results.

You can use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to tell it to strip these out.

```
$file = file("index.html", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```